# how to override element type in xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to use an existing xml schema (let's call it xsd1) ==> some types  and groupes in the xsd1 needs to be redefined.
the idea is to use a new xsd (let's call it xsd2) and include xsd1 content and redefine only some types (keeping the same name of types)

like. 
xsd1:

```
- type1 : integer > 0
- type2 : integer
- type3 : double
```

xsd2

```
include xsd1
type2: string
```

how to do that ?

Comment: here's a nice example about that http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter18.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 the xs:redefines construct allows you to redefine selected components of a schema, but only in a way that is compatible with the original (the new schema can restrict what instances are allowed, but cannot extend what is allowed - which is what you are trying to do).

In XSD 1.1 the xs:override construct allows arbitrary redefinition of selected components, without compatibility constraints.

Both cause severe complications if you need the two versions of the schema components to coexist.